# Change Beacon transmission rate to 5Hz

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I use this code to start a ibacon with a 10hz transmission rate.

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 01
```

Are the min and max values little endian ? I want to be sure that this value that my command is right.

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 50 00 50 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
```

Will this command change the transmission rate to 5Hz? And is the optimal scan period for this rate is 400ms ?

Answer (score 1):

The min and max values are little endian, yes.  So in this command:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 50 00 50 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
```

The first two bytes `50 00` sets the min interval to 0x0050 (80 decimal), which at a granularity of 0.625 ms converts to 80x0.625 = 50.0 ms.  The second two bytes sets the max interval to 50.0 ms as well.  To convert to Hz, you take the reciprocal of the interval 1/(0.050 secs) = 20 Hz.

You say you want 5 Hz, which would be one advertisement every 1/(5 Hz) = 0.2 secs = 200 ms.  At a granularity of 0.625 ms, that is 200/0.625 = 320 = 0x0140.  Expressed as little endian this is 0x40 0x01.   So to advertise at 5 Hz, do:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 40 01 40 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
```

Your bluetooth chip may or many not support this rate.  You will have to try and see.  If it doesn't support it, you probably will get no errors, it just will advertise at its closest supported rate.

If you are scanning for this advertisement using the Android Beacon Library or some other library that lets you configure the scan interval, a default scan interval of ~1.0 sec will work fine.